# $(<input=file>).trigger('click') is not working consistently only for Ipad/Iphone Safari

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, safari, touch-event

I have a backbone project where on click of image icon, I am trying to open photo library pop up . 
The issue is , photo library pop up opens sometimes but only when i click on right half of the image button. 
I have gone through many answers regarding similar problem and tried everything but the issue still persists for me . Please help.

View for Button has 
  tagName: "button",
  className: "image-uploader",

and i am handling its click like this

$(input type="file"  name="image" accept="image/*" width="0px"; height="0px"; overflow="hidden"; position="relative"; top="-100px").trigger('click');

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the problem, format the code by indenting (4 spaces) inside your question, add details to help understand the problem, it is possibly a css issue as well... Good luck

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting the image using some id or class?
like

```
$(".image-uploader").trigger('click');
```

or

```
this.$el.trigger('click');
```

as you are using backbone.js you might have its element saved somewhere in your view. Try accessing using view's $el